# Compiler forces to handle rethrow of unchecked exception

Tags: java, exception

I have encountered a scenario while working with exceptions, following is the sample code.I am trying to understand why following code fails to compile. I am checking the exception type before rethrow which is unchecked exception.

```
public class TestException {

    public void test() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileReader test = new FileReader("");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestException test=new TestException();
        try {
            test.test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
                throw e;
            }
            else{
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `throw e;` line is throwing `Exception`, although you know it is an instance of `ArithmeticException`, the type of `e` is still `Exception`.

Comment: `Exception` is not unchecked.

Comment: why not two separate catch blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You are still throwing a reference variable `e` of type `Exception`. `Exception` is a *checked* type. The compiler only knows the reference variable's type, not the referenced object's. If you want to keep `main`'s method signature as-is, you'll need to either wrap `e` into an unchecked exception type (such as `ArithmeticException`):

```
if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
     throw new ArithmeticException(e.getMessage());
 }
```

or cast it as an unchecked exception:

```
if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
     throw (ArithmeticException)e;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the reference variable `e` is of type `java.lang.Exception`, `throw e` will throw checked exception. Thus it has to be declared in `throws` section in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your catch block as follows:-

```
if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
     throw (ArithmeticException)e;
 }
 else{
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use two catch blocks.
typechecking in catch block is not a good practice where you can catch that specific class using other catch statement.

```
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    throw e;
 }
catch(Exception e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

@Silly Freak I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a hack with Generics to throw an checked Exception as an unchecked one:

http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2010/02/throwing-checked-excpetions-like-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/

I like to use this over `throw new RuntimeException(e)`, since the latter creates unnecessary output in a Stacktrace and its harder to catch somewhere else (you have to check the cause instead of the excetion itself).

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e) {
```

Here is the effective declaration of `e`.

```
    if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
```

Here you are doing a *runtime* check of the type of `e.`

```
        throw e;
```

At this point the compile-time type of `e` is `Exception`. So the compiler enforces its rules.

Answer (score -1):

If you throw any exception then you should handle it but in your program your are able to throw but nowhere you are handling the exception, so just handle the exception by adding `throws` in main class like this:-

```
package first;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;


class A3{

    public void test() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileReader test = new FileReader("");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        A3 test=new A3();
        try {
            test.test();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            if(e instanceof ArithmeticException){
                throw e;
            }
            else{
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```